# What kind of permissions should an Identity Server handle?

Tags: security, oauth, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

We currently have a REST web service who's permission depends on the role and who the user is (if the user is a student, admin or the author of a certain entity). This kind of permission is check within the controllers. We're considering the use of an identity server such as WSO2 IS.

If we use an IS, should we migrate the existing permissions check to IS? If so, what I currently understand is it will add an overhead since IS will validate every request. Enlighten me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original aim OAuth2 is a permission delegation - a user allows an application to access the his/hers resources or to perform actions on the user's behalf. OpenID Connec (OAuth2 extension) is meant for user authentication.

You have two kinds of permissions - roles and permissions bound to resources (entities). You probably cannot check the access to the resources (eg. whether the user is author of an entity) at the OAuth2 server, since it's not aware of it. You could transform roles to individual actions (scopes) and check whether the user's access token contains the required scope. But you would have to ask for all possible scopes of your application on user authentication. Some forms of the access tokens and scopes (JWT) can be verified even without accessing the server.

You can also use the OAuth2 server just for authentication, get the list of user groups and keep the existing access control based on user roles and resource ownership. It would make the transition easy and later, if you find out that you need something more, there will be no wasted effort.